# spring boot and twitter bootstrap

Tags: spring

I am currently developing website application with spring mvc, the problem i have right now is that jsp page does not see the bootstrap libraries imported by maven, the libraries are imported under java resources-libraries-maven dependencies.[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nCSY.png)

Below is my application-servlet.xml file.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/public/**" location="classpath:/public/" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.bookstore.controller" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="validation" />
</bean>

<bean id="loginValidation" class="com.bookstore.validationHelpers.LoginValidator" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

***

and am references it from the jsp with the following

but i get an error its not being found but the boostrap3 libraries have been successfully downloaded, please help. thanks

Comment: I have also tried this line <mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/" /> but with no success

Comment: By jsp reference link is <link rel='stylesheet' href='webjars/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.css'>

Comment: How do you reference the css files in the JSP? Also you should use the default folder structure for Maven, which means, that resources are stored in the folder src/main/resources. Also Spring Boot adds a special mapping for static resources, so they should be in the folder src/main/resources/static.